# Why does Javascript that is ran in google console only set a selector to the last value either in a loop or just stardard flow

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm attempting to set a value on an input based on a selector, when I try to set the value more than once it only ever sets the last value, I was doing this in a for loop but for simplicity, the results here are the same;

```
var input = document.querySelector("#challengeInput-36757ce5057c429fae3c0ea0a4e65e16-answer");
input.value = 1;
sleepFor(2000);
input.value = 2;

function sleepFor(sleepDuration) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration) {
        /* Do nothing */
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded, meaning it can't run your code AND update the DOM at the same time. So you will only see the input updated after your code has run to completion.

To push events to a later time, while allowing things to happen in between, such as updating the DOM, you need to push a callback onto the event queue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#queue

The simplest way to do that is with `setTimeout`.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
input.value = 1;
setTimeout(() => input.value = 2, 1000)
setTimeout(() => input.value = 3, 2000)
```

```html
<input />
```

---

If you want the same event to be pushed to the back of the event queue after running, you can use `setInterval`

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
let value = 1;
input.value = value;
setInterval(() => input.value = ++value, 1000)
```

```html
<input />
```